# Replacing netcat when using react-native run-ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

System details
MacOS Mojave
Node: 10.15

My current organization blocks suspicious use of Netcat /usr/bin/nc . One work around we discussed is creating a symlink to nc and having react-native run-ios use that symlink instead.

Is there a way to tell react-native to use a different netcat or avoid use of it all together?